# Diashow-like CSS transition of div on button click in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this HTLM snippet in my angular project:

```
<div class="orderslide content-decoration mt-5">
    <app-orderdata class="orderslide" *ngIf="orderstepsbuttons.orderdata.active" [context]='this'></app-orderdata>
    <app-ordercontact class="orderslide" *ngIf="orderstepsbuttons.ordercontact.active" [context]='this'></app-ordercontact>
    <app-orderreceiver *ngIf="orderstepsbuttons.orderreceiver.active" [context]='this'></app-orderreceiver>
    <app-orderdeliverydata *ngIf="orderstepsbuttons.orderdeliverydata.active" [context]='this'></app-orderdeliverydata>
    <app-orderproducts *ngIf="orderstepsbuttons.orderproducts.active" [context]='this'></app-orderproducts>
    <app-ordersummary *ngIf="orderstepsbuttons.ordersummary.active" [context]='this'></app-ordersummary>
    <app-orderstepsbuttons [context]='this'></app-orderstepsbuttons>
 </div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.orderslide {
    -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.7s forwards;
    -moz-animation: slideIn 0.7s forwards;
    animation: slideIn 0.7s forwards;
}    

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(-900px);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
      }
      @-moz-keyframes slideIn {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(-900px);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
      }
      @keyframes slideIn {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(-900px);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }
```

Also i have a button which is not displayed here. It basically activates the different app-components within the div. Only one of those app-components is active at a time.
The idea is that the div slides in from left on every button click, so everytime an app-component is loaded.

How can i achive to apply the CSS on every button click?

Comment: Using Angular animations in your Angular project, you can accomplish the sliding effect with each button click